# Using 'react-ad-msal' with React Native for authentication

Tags: azure, react-native, authentication, azure-active-directory

Is there a possibility to use this library with React-Native and if yes please provide me a link with a sample because I couldnt find any?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **react-native-azure-auth** package but I am not tried yet, repo not up to date.

With yarn

```
yarn add react-native-azure-auth
```

or with npm

```
npm i react-native-azure-auth --save
```

Don't forget to make a link.

```
react-native link react-native-azure-auth
```

**EDITED**

If you're react-native version >= 0.60, don't linking.

[Github repo](https://github.com/vmurin/react-native-azure-auth)

Comment: does it serve the same purpose like the one in my question? Any differences?

Comment: Purpose is same but. Your package just JavaScript codes, this is native. So, binding android/ios native codes  with JavaScript.

Comment: To be honest I dont understand what you said! Can you please edit your answer?

Comment: I think you should understand the difference between react and react-native and their life cycles.